# Finding and replacing a value in xml in python

Tags: python, xml

XML Format looks like this :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?> 

 <con:PropertySet xmlns:con="HTTP://example.com/SCHEMA"> <con:properties>

 <con:property> 

 <con:description>test1</con:description>

 <con:name>Kate</con:name> 

 <con:defaultValue>

 <con:value>false</con:value> 

 </con:defaultValue 

 </con:property>

 <con:property> 

 <con:description>test2</con:description>

 <con:name>Nathan</con:name> 

 <con:defaultValue>

 <con:value>false</con:value> 

 </con:defaultValue 

 </con:property>

 </con:properties> 

 </con:PropertySet>
```

I tried the code as a beginner:

```
with open(test.xml, encoding="utf8") as f:

    tree = ET.parse(f)

    print("tree : ", tree)

    myroot = tree.getroot()

    print("myroot",myroot)

    result = len(myroot.getchildren())

    print("length", result)

    for elem in myroot.iter():

        try:

          value_find = myroot.find("./PropertySet/properties/property/defaultValue/[@value='false']")

          print("property", value_find)
```

Last print statement is not giving any output. There is no output.
Here I am trying to achieve is replace false with true of tag  based on Name = Kate.
Can you please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con:PropertySet xmlns:con="HTTP://example.com/SCHEMA">
   <con:properties>
      <con:property>
         <con:description>test1</con:description>
         <con:name>Kate</con:name>
         <con:defaultValue>
            <con:value>false</con:value>
         </con:defaultValue>
      </con:property>
      <con:property>
         <con:description>test2</con:description>
         <con:name>Nathan</con:name>
         <con:defaultValue>
            <con:value>false</con:value>
         </con:defaultValue>
      </con:property>
   </con:properties>
</con:PropertySet>'''

namespaces = {'con': 'HTTP://example.com/SCHEMA'}
ET.register_namespace('con', 'HTTP://example.com/SCHEMA')

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
kates = [e for e in root.findall('.//con:property', namespaces) if e.find('con:name', namespaces).text == 'Kate']
for kate in kates:
    kate.find('.//con:value', namespaces).text = 'true'
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<con:PropertySet xmlns:con="HTTP://example.com/SCHEMA">
   <con:properties>
      <con:property>
         <con:description>test1</con:description>
         <con:name>Kate</con:name>
         <con:defaultValue>
            <con:value>true</con:value>
         </con:defaultValue>
      </con:property>
      <con:property>
         <con:description>test2</con:description>
         <con:name>Nathan</con:name>
         <con:defaultValue>
            <con:value>false</con:value>
         </con:defaultValue>
      </con:property>
   </con:properties>
</con:PropertySet>
```